# How can i set field value in grid form Ms Access via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, grid

The problem is that i have two forms. First is parent form, second is daughter grid-like form.
On parent form there are some maniplations which must fill in some fields in daughter form.
Its like "Update Set Where" query in SQL, but in this grid. After all manipulation i press button "Save" and only then changes save into DB

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the child form using the following syntax in VBA

```
Me.Controls("YourSubFormName").Form.Controls("ControlOnYourTargetForm").Text = ..
```

However, if you have a datasheet view of your form then you need to modify the underlying data, since the form is tightly data bound and reflects the chnanges in your data. You can't just add a new line here as you would do in a "normal" GridView in .Net etc.

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing control referencing formatted this way but I really like it. I wish that MS Access had Early Binding with Full Intellisense for accessing controls, public procedures, public functions, and public variables across different forms, subforms, parent forms, etc. It's one of my chief complaints with MS Access.